# Cant insert dynamic cron using php

Tags: php, cron

My res_time.php file has a line

```
$r = $shell_exec("/var/www/html/new12345/cront1.sh $n");
```

where `cront1.sh` is

```
!/bin/bash
echo " 00 $1 * * * /var/www/html/new12345/shell_call.php >> /var/www/html/w.txt" | crontab -
```

when i manually enter `./cront1.sh 3` i can see an entry in crontab

However using bash within php is creating some problems..the line itself is not called..HELP!

Permissions are full to each file reffered

Comment: IS the PHP script being called on CLI or via a browser? If the latter, does the Web server user have permission to execute `cront1.sh`?

Comment: no in a browser..oooh then u mean apache should be given permission to execute cron1.sh

Comment: Yep :-) And bear in mind that the crontab will be against the apache user, so make sure it's allowed a crontab.

Comment: hey how to give permission for that??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the right way to go about things. Generally, you want to involve the OS-level cron as little as possible. The way most frameworks go about it is to have a single cron script, called every few minutes or so, which then decides what other tasks need doing, and does them.

So you'd set up a single entry in Crontab, something like:

```
*/3 * * * * /var/www/html/my_site/cron.php
```

At a basic level, you can work out what to do in cron.php by running modulo operations on the current timestamp, e.g.

```
if (time() % (60*60)) {
    // runs every hour, on the hour
}

if (time() % ((60*60)/2)) {
    // runs at xx:00 and xx:30
}


if (time() % (60*5)) {
    // runs every five minutes
    // although it'll actually only run every 15 mins, because cron.php is called every 3 mins!
}
```

Comment: but i need to schedule this according to users wish which is not constant...so any other idea?

Comment: It might be better to configure the cron to run a lightweight PHP / bash script fairly regularly, and have that script do your user-specific checks (e.g. by checking database or similar).